# What approach for creating and editing database structure: code or scripts?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

Let's say there's an application which should create its own tables in main database if they are missing (for example application is run for a very first time). What way of doing this is more flexible, scalable and, let's say, more suitable for commercial product?

If I code it all no additional files (scripts) are needed. User won't be able to make something stupid with them and then complain that application doesn't work. But when something will change in db structure I have to code patching part and user will have to install new binary (or just replace the old one).

Scripting solution would be a few lines of code for just run all scripts from some directory and bunch of scripts. Binary could be the same, patching would be applied automatically. But new scripts also have to be deployed to user at some point.

So, what would you recommend?

Application will be coded in c#, database for now will be under SQLServer 2005 but it may change in the future. Of course, drawing application and database handling part can be separated into two binaries/assemblies but it doesn't solves my code vs. scripts dilemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Wizardby](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/): it provides a special language (somewhat close to SQL DDL) to express changes to your database schema:

```
migration "Blog" revision => 1:
    type-aliases:
        type-alias N type => String, length => 200, nullable => false, default => ""

    defaults:
        default-primary-key ID type => Int32, nullable => false, identity => true

    version 20090226100407:
        add table Author: /* Primary Key is added automatically */
            FirstName type => N /* “add” can be omitted */
            LastName type => N
            EmailAddress type => N, unique => true /* "unique => true" will create UQ_EmailAddress index */
            Login type => N, unique => true
            Password type => Binary, length => 64, nullable => true

            index UQ_LoginEmailAddress unique => true, columns => [[Login, asc], EmailAddress]

        add table Tag:
            Name type => N

        add table Blog:
            Name type => N
            Description type => String, nullable => false

        add table BlogPost:
            Title type => N
            Slug type => N
            BlogID references => Blog /* Column type is inferred automatically */
            AuthorID: 
                reference pk-table => Author
```

These `version` blocks are basically changes you want to be applied to your database schema.

Wizardby can also be integrated into your build process, as well as into your application: on each startup in can attempt to upgrade database to the most recent version. Thus your application will always work with most up-to-date schema version.

It can also be integrated into your setup process: Wizardby can generate SQL scripts to alter database schema, and these can be run as part of your setup process.

Comment: Is this a vote for the code instead for scripts? It looks interesting by I can write mechanism like this using SMO for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually want to keep my installation code separate from my application code.  You will definitely want your application performing some sort of version check against the database to ensure it has the proper structure it requires before running though.  The basic setup I would follow is this:

1. Use scripts with each released
   version to make schema changes to
   the deployed database.
2. Have something in your database to track current version of the
   database, perhaps a simple version
   table that tracks which scripts have
   been run against it.  It's simpler
   to look for the version script than
   to check the schema every time and
   search for all the tables and fields
   you need.
3. Have your application check the database version marker to ensure it
   meets the application's version. 
   Log an error that will let the user
   know they have to update their
   database with the database scripts.

That should keep your application code clean, but make sure database and app are in sync.

Comment: I thought about "last applied version" stored in database but still, why scripts not code? I can check db version and run patching code as well as run scripts. If app v4 uses a new table I have to add that table to db anyway but, again, why by scripts not by code?

Comment: As I mentioned at the beginning, my personal preference is to try to keep installation code away from my application code.  That's not to say you COULD NOT run scripts from the code, or have code that makes the changes, but rather that placing it into the application business layer pollutes it.

If you prefer making DB changes using code rather than release scripts, you could always create a separate 'versioning' app that ensures a database is upgraded correctly to the required version.  This would separate the two application concepts, while not forcing you into using scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Then using a versioning tool like DBGhost or [DVC](http://code.google.com/p/databaseversioncontrol) would help you to maintain database updates and could be modified to fit seamlessly into your application.